# In how many ways can one book be selected from $D$ of $B$ boxes, each of which contains $N$ books, if all books are distinct?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem that doesn't seem that complicated, but I cannot get my head around it.

We got $B$ boxes with $N$ books *each* in it.

All books are distinct, so we got $B \cdot N$ books.

We can pick one book from $D$ distinct boxes.

How many combinations of books are possible?

For example, I have $4$ boxes each containing $2$ books and I pick from $2$ boxes.

That would mean $B=4$, $N=2$ and $D=2$. Each book is unique. It means we have a total of $8$ books. Doing this specific case by hand gives me $24$ combinations.

Comment: Do we pick from *up to* $D$ boxes or exactly $D$ boxes?  If we pick from a box, how many books do we pick from it?  Any number including zero?  Any number that is at least one?

Comment: Sry @JMoravitz, I updated the question , we pick up exactly one book from a box, an d we pick up exactly from D distinct boxes.

Comment: Pick which $D$ boxes are used in $\binom{B}{D}$ ways.  For each box that was chosen, pick which book was taken from it in $N$ ways.  Apply multiplication principle.  This gives $\binom{B}{D}N^D$ total ways.

Comment: @JMoravitz Don't hesitate to post this as a solution.